# Javascript - 2nd button click clears my div

Tags: javascript

im fairly new to JS and ive created a formula to do some calculations and put them into a div when its done. My problem is on the first button press it works like a charm. When i press the button a second time it deletes the text in my div and doesnt redo the calculation.

Its probably some silly mistake i cant find but id appreciate any help. The Code looks like this:

```js
    function formChanged() {
      var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
    }

    document.getElementById('button').click = function calc() {

      var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x").value);
      var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y").value);

      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "pre-text";

      while (y < x) {
       document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "text" + x + "more text";;
        y++;
      }

      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "post-text";

    }
```

```html
 <form>
      <input value="20" id="x" type="text" onkeyup="formChanged()" onchange="formChanged()">
      <input value="1" id="y" type="text" onkeyup="formChanged()" onchange="formChanged()">
      <button type="button" id="button">Calc</button>
    </form>

    <div id="test" style="height:400px; width:500px; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
```

I tried to slim it down a bit since its a bigger loop with calculation etc. The function itself works fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "post-text";
```

this part removes your div content, just change it with :

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "post-text";
```

Calc

Full working code:

```
<div id="test" style="height:400px; width:500px; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>

<script>

function calc() {
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x").value);
    var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y").value);

    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "pre-text";

    while (y < x) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "text" + x + "more text";;
        y++;
    }

    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "post-text";

}
</script>
```

And ofcourse you can use `element.addEventListener("click", calc)`like **SimpleJ** mentioned.

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", calc);
```

Comment: Thanks guys that helped.

Answer (score -1):

I copied your code into a file and tried it. Your button doesn't do anything.

**Edit**: As @SimpleJ stated, calling globally is a bad practice. I updated the answer.

```
function calc(){
    // function body
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", calc);
```

This way the `calc()` function is actually called when you click the button. It's called *adding an EventListener* if you need some term to Google for further reference.

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: I suggest using `element.addEventListener("click", calc)` instead of calling global functions from HTML.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the answer as you suggested. I'm usually using the Meteor Framework, that's why I'm not used to writing *raw* JavaScript ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please be so kind and accept one of the two proposed answers :)